# Как вычислить точную разницу между датами в годах на Java Script?

Tags: javascript

Как определить точную разницу в годах между текущей датой и датой в формате "0000-00-00 00:00:00". На PHP это решается просто:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", '2014-09-12 00:00:00')
->diff(new DateTime('now'))
->y;
```

Есть подобное элегантное решение на Java Script?

Comment: используя библиотеку типа momentjs можно делать почти так же. А можно просто вычислить - разница дат - это количество миллисекунд - осталось только перевести миллисекунды в года

Comment: @Grundy в этом и сложность. до дней и недель все переводится просто, а чтобы корректно перевести в месяцы и годы простой формулой не обойтись.

Comment: @Grundy не хотелось бы подключать отдельную библиотеку ради одной функции.

Comment: [Связанный вопрос на английском](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4060004/2881286)

Comment: Проще, все-таки, подключить библиотеку. Либо посмотреть [как в ней это реализовано](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/src/lib/moment/diff.js)

Comment: @Grundy да, думал переписать эту функцию под себя, но проще тогда просто отправлять на сервер, там все равно идет та же валидация.

Comment: Тут все зависит от того на сколько точный должен быть расчет и для чего он будет использоваться потом. По ссылке выше есть еще несколько вариантов.

Comment: @Grundy нужен точный расчет. в частности, это решение будет использоваться в функции валидации даты, но планирую сделать универсальным и для других вещей.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56240/discussion-between-grundy-and-dmitry-maslennikov).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итоговый код. На вход идет дата в формате '0000-00-00 00:00:00', на выходе количество полных лет с текущей даты:

```
function age_count(date) {
    // now
    var now = new Date();
    now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() - now.getTimezoneOffset());
    now = now.toISOString().substr(0, 19).replace('T',' ');
    // calculate
    var age = now.substr(0, 4) - date.substr(0, 4);
    if(now.substr(5) < date.substr(5)) --age;
    // output
    return age;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Создать два объекта Date – день рождения и сейчас. Чтобы гарантированно правильно получить из текстовой строки, как у вас, объект даты, надо привести её сначала к формату [ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime). Проще всего заменить пробел на букву "T". Но такая дата будет в часовом поясе UTC, надо её скорректировать, добавив минуты из getTimezoneOffset(). Например, дата "2014-09-12 00:00:00" по Мск, это 11 сентября 21:00 по UTC. При сравнении из «сейчас» будем тоже брать время по UTC – getUTCMonth() и т.п.

Получив две даты, сравним их месяцы и дни. Если требуется бОльшая точность, то ещё и часы, минуты, секунды:

```
var sqlDT = "2014-09-12 00:00:00";
var BD = new Date( sqlDT.replace(' ','T'));
var Now = new Date();
BD.setMinutes( BD.getMinutes() + Now.getTimezoneOffset()); // в UTC

if( BD.getMonth() === Now.getUTCMonth()
  && BD.getDate() === Now.getUTCDate()
) {
  // ура! День рождения!
  var y = Now.getUTCFullYear() - BD.getFullYear(); // сколько полных лет
}
```

Альтернативный вариант – подключить библиотеку для работы с датами и временем – [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/docs/), и найти подходящие методы в ней.

Comment: при переводе в формат UTC некорректно обрабатывается разница. например, между '2017-03-29 21:00:00' и '2015-03-29 19:00:00' результат вычислений будет 1, а не 2 (правильный, если использовать без форматирования).

Comment: если что, часовой пояс - москва, +3.

Comment: @DmitryMaslennikov неправильный результат потому, что вы, видимо, криво корректировали код. Вот [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/kgbj0y49/) где сравниваются две любые текстовые даты – там получается 2. И вот [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/d0x924rw/), где сравнивается '2015-03-29 19:00:00' и сейчас (я в UTC+3) – получается 2.

Comment: не пойму тогда в чем дело, вот fiddle с моим кодом, переписанным в рекомендованном вами стиле: https://jsfiddle.net/d0x924rw/4/

Comment: по дате там все правильно работает, но на часах уже выдает неверный результат. попробуйте ввести переменные +/- час от текущего времени.

Comment: но с другим годом (в моем примере 2015, но любые значения выдают 1).

Comment: поправил свой код по вашим рекомендациям, он в моем ответе. единственный момент, как более компактно записать преобразование текущего времени к нужному формату (0000-00-00 00:00:00)?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы под точной разницей имели в виду именно значение года, а не годы по количеству прошедших месяцев, то можно так:

```js
var unix_date = "2016-01-01 00:00:00"; 
var jsYear = new Date(unix_date).getFullYear(); 
var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
var yearsDifference = currentYear - jsYear;
console.log(yearsDifference);
```

Comment: нет, именно именно второй вариант (по количеству прошедших месяцев, но нужна точность до секунды). нашел решение, см. ниже